# Matplotlib figure windows cannot be focused or switched to through cmd+tab

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib 2.2.2.` with `ipython 3.6.5` (both from anaconda) for data analysis. Whenever I create a figure window with some boilerplate code like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.plot()
```

I get a nice figure window to which I can only switch focus by using with the mouse. These figure windows are not part of the list of macosx application switcher (accessible through cmd+tab shortcut). I've tried the osx and the qt5 backends, but I get the same results as described before.

Do you know any solution/workaround for this? It would be *very* practical to be able to switch focus between figure windows from the keyboard, as I often find myself browsing through the figure windows looking for the graph I'm interested in. Moreover, if matplotlib's figure windows were actual cocoa/macos windows, it would be extremely useful to those out there who use tiling window managers on osx.

Comment: Thanks Ishara Madhawa for helping me format my question properly!

Comment: Is this dependent on whether you use `plt.ion()` or not or would you observe the same without `plt.ion()`.

Comment: Thanks ImportanceOfBeingErnest! Whether I use `plt.ion()` or not, I observe the same behaviour: cmd+tab does not allow me to switch focus to matplotlib's figure window. Can you offer me some pointers as to why I get this? Or is this the natural, expected behaviour? Thanks again!

Comment: No, if it's the same behaviour, I have no clue. In that case it's probably a macos problem rather than a matplotlib problem and I haven't ever worked with macs.